# Property 'host' does not exist on type 'ProxyTargetUrl' Error. Even though i get IntelliSense in JS File

Tags: typescript, types, visual-studio-code

I have the following code in a `.ts` file:

```
const connection = {
        host: options.target.host
      };
```

`options` are of type `httpProxy.ServerOptions` and `target` is of type `ProxyTargetUrl`

The error i get is the following:

```
Property 'host' does not exist on type 'ProxyTargetUrl'.
  Property 'host' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

These options are part from the `http-proxy` npm module. The newest typings are installed. `"@types/http-proxy": "^1.16.2"`

When i follow the declaration i see this:

```
type ProxyTargetUrl = string | url.Url;
```

--

```
interface Url extends UrlObjectCommon {
        port?: string;
        query?: string | null | ParsedUrlQuery;
    }
```

--

```
interface UrlObjectCommon {
        auth?: string;
        hash?: string;
        host?: string;
        hostname?: string;
        href?: string;
        path?: string;
        pathname?: string;
        protocol?: string;
        search?: string;
        slashes?: boolean;
    }
```

Why do i get this error? When i copy my code over in a JS File i get IntelliSense for the `host` property and the code also works perfectly fine at runtime. So the typings are correct. What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your union type `type ProxyTargetUrl = string | url.Url`, only `Url` has field `host` defined.

To access this field, you would need a type assertion: `(<Url>options.target).host`.

See [this Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12815) for more information.